# Identifying an Object edge from a predefined object using image processing

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

I want to identify an object edge.

For example [image: Object]

this is my main object. I want to identify the edge of the shirt when given below image.

[image: Proto Type]

Something like this. Can anyone give me some methods to how to figure this out!!!!

Comment: I don't identify the template in the image. The collar differs and the arms too. I think you're thinking a bit too high-level about object recognition. About the question: One prominent object detection by edges method is "chamfer matching". Give it a try.

Comment: You can try to use template matching method given in openCV like cv2.matchTemplate() for this purpose.